# Using older version of maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to use an older version of maven-checkstyle-plugin that 2.15 which is tad old than the current 2.17; even though I have explicitly mentioned about 2.15 in my pom.xml; the maven build still picks up 2.17 which seems mysterious to me. I could force it to use by having it mentioned in the command line

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:checkstyle
```

but want to get it straight through the pom.xml; any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you defined iit in your parent pom via pluginManagement?

Comment: that was indeed the problem; I had the version 2.15 used in the reporting section but on plugin management.